# Keras Python script sometimes runs fine, sometimes fails with Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [10000,1], In[1]: [3,1]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, classification

I want Keras to recognize selfies and non-selfies, first I am developing with only 4 pictures before using the full data.

**Problem**: The script sometimes runs and exits normally, sometimes it fails with the error `Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [10000,1], In[1]: [3,1]` below:

```
$ python run.py
TensorFlow version: 1.10.1
file_names: ['selfies-dev-data/0/lego.jpg', 'selfies-dev-data/0/dakota.jpg', 'selfies-dev-data/1/ammar.jpg', 'selfies-dev-data/1/olivier.jpg']
labels: [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0]
dataset: <PrefetchDataset shapes: ((?, 100, 100, 1), (?, 1)), types: (tf.float32, tf.float32)>
images: Tensor("IteratorGetNext:0", shape=(?, 100, 100, 1), dtype=float32)
labels: Tensor("IteratorGetNext:1", shape=(?, 1), dtype=float32)
Epoch 1/1
2018-09-25 13:59:17.285143: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
1/2 [==============>...............] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.7741 - acc: 0.0000e+00Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 64, in <module>
    model.fit(images, labels, epochs=1, steps_per_epoch=2)
  File "/home/nico/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1363, in fit
    validation_steps=validation_steps)
  File "/home/nico/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_arrays.py", line 205, in fit_loop
    outs = f(ins)
  File "/home/nico/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py", line 2914, in __call__
    fetched = self._callable_fn(*array_vals)
  File "/home/nico/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1382, in __call__
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/nico/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 519, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [10000,1], In[1]: [3,1]
         [[Node: rgb_to_grayscale/Tensordot/MatMul = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=false, transpose_b=false](rgb_to_grayscale/Tensordot/Reshape, rgb_to_grayscale/Tensordot/Reshape_1)]]
         [[Node: IteratorGetNext = IteratorGetNext[output_shapes=[[?,100,100,1], [?,1]], output_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](OneShotIterator)]]
```

How to investigate the problem? The code resizes the images to 100*100 and the input layer is also 100*100, I don't know where the `3` comes from.

For reference, here is my source code:

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
print "TensorFlow version: " + tf.__version__

out_shape = tf.convert_to_tensor([100, 100])
batch_size = 2

data_folders = ["selfies-dev-data/0", "selfies-dev-data/1"]
classes = [0., 1.]
epoch_size = len(data_folders)

file_names = [] # Path of all data files
labels = [] # Label of each data file (same size as the array above)
for d, l in zip(data_folders, classes):
    name = [os.path.join(d,f) for f in os.listdir(d)] # get the list of all the images file names
    file_names.extend(name)
    labels.extend([l] * len(name))

print "file_names: " + str(file_names)
print "labels: " +str(labels)

file_names = tf.convert_to_tensor(file_names, dtype=tf.string)
labels = tf.convert_to_tensor(labels)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((file_names, labels))
dataset = dataset.repeat().shuffle(epoch_size)

def map_fn(path, label):
    # path/label represent values for a single example
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(tf.read_file(path))

    # some mapping to constant size - be careful with distorting aspect ratios
    image = tf.image.resize_images(image, out_shape)
    image = tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(image)

    # color normalization - just an example
    image = tf.to_float(image) * (2. / 255) - 1
    label = tf.expand_dims(label, axis=-1)
    return image, label

# num_parallel_calls > 1 induces intra-batch shuffling
dataset = dataset.map(map_fn, num_parallel_calls=8)
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
dataset = dataset.prefetch(1)
print "dataset: " + str(dataset)

images, labels = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()

# Following is from https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/basic_classification
from tensorflow import keras

model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(100, 100, 1)),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)
])

model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(),
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

print "images: " + str(images)
print "labels: " + str(labels)
model.fit(images, labels, epochs=1, steps_per_epoch=2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be in the following line:

```
image = tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(image)
```

[`tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/rgb_to_grayscale) expects the given image tensor to have a last dimension with size 3, representing the RGB channels. However, the line:

```
image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(tf.read_file(path))
```

Can produce tensors with a different number of channels. This is because [`tf.image.decode_jpeg`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/decode_jpeg) will, by default, make a tensor with the same number of channels than those in the JPEG data. So if you have an image that is already grayscale then the tensor will have only one channel and the program will fail. You can solve the problem by requesting to decode the JPEG data as an RGB image in all cases, setting the `channels` parameter to `3`:

```
image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(tf.read_file(path), channels=3)
```

This will ensure that all your images are treated uniformly.